# Advice on methods for custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know if my approach to validate new record is good or not.

I don't use the common RoR validation system, so in my model I have all custom validation mathods like these:

```
  def validates_user_name(user)
    ...
  end

  def validates_user_surname(user)
    ...
  end

  ...
```

that I call from controller in this way

```
def create
  ...
  @user.validates_user_name(params[:user])
  @user.validates_user_name(params[:user])
  ...
end
```

**Is it a good way** to validate the creation of new user? There will be problems with hackers using this approach?

Comment: I'm just curious why you don't use the built-in ActiveRecord validations. That is definitely one way to do it, but I'd probably have a `validate_user(params[:user])` method that took care of everything.

Comment: Because I want to have more and more control on validation: like that I can call validation methods when I want and where I want: how I want!  ;-)

Comment: user502052: Going "against the flow" of Rails and creating your own validations is frowned upon. Generally, most validation things can be taken care of by Rails. If it cannot, then that is where you would use validations. Perhaps you could edit your answer to include what the validations are doing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have a hard time convincing anyone that your custom validations are better than what's built into Rails, especially if the validation logic is similar.

If you still want control over when things happen, you should take advantage of the built-in callback hooks like [before_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). There are lots of advantages of doing it this way, including automatic transaction rollback and decoupling. However, if what you're doing is already accomplished by Rails, it's not advisable to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I must "satisfy" your "patience": I DO NOT want to convince anyone that MY custom validations are better than what's built into Rails... mhmmh, where did you read that?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by satisfying my patience.

Comment: It is a simple ironic/polemic phrase.